# Why device not connecting to the emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, device, galaxy

I have two devices

**`1. Samsung Galaxy Ace GT-S5830`**

**`2. Samsung Galaxy Ace GT-S5830i`**

If I am connecting the **1st** device to the emulator then it gets connected and working fine as a debugger.

But If I am connecting the **2nd** device to the emulator of the same Computer then it not getting connected to the emulator.

And on the notification of **1st** device i.e. **Galaxy Ace GT-S5830** looks like this:

[image]

where as on the **second device** i.e. **Galaxy Ace GT-S5830i**, The USB Debugging Connected notification is missing.

[image]

```
I have marked Setting ---> Application ---> Development ---> USB Debugging as Checked. Then to why I am getting this issue.
```

Please if any one know about this,then please let me know to resolve this problem. I want to use Samsung **Galaxy Ace GT-S5830i** as a debugging device.

Comment: have you rooted your device??

Comment: @manindersingh Can you please tell me how to root the device?

Comment: I just want that my device should work as emulator. This is strenge for me that for galaxy Ace GT-S5830, its working fine but not for galaxy Ace GT-S5830i.

Answer (score 0):

No need to root the device, install google universal usb drivers from the SDK manager.

Comment: It is already installed in my case. So please tell me what to do for this to be done

Comment: install the drivers of your phone and where are you looking for the device to show up?

Comment: check if you are connecting it on USB mass storage mode.

Comment: Yes you have to turn off the USB mass storage mode to use the debugging mode.

Comment: I am not able to find this option in my device. Any help

Comment: I just want that my device should work as emulator. This is strenge for me that for galaxy Ace GT-S5830, its working fine but not for galaxy Ace GT-S5830i.